# Create a UTF-8 Encoded File Using Chef on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, character-encoding, chef-infra

I am using Chef to create a UDL file on Windows 12.  The file must be encoded as UTF-8, but I can't get Chef to produce anything other than ANSI.

On the workstation, the template file is UTF-8 encoded, but the template file that ends up on the target nodes is ANSI when it lands in the chef cache -- so it seems the encoding is being lost during the file transfer to the target node. The target node's ruby is defaulting to UTF-8 during the chef-client run, although I expect that because the source ERB template is ANSI, the target is being created as ANSI as well.

The recipe is pretty straightforward:

```
log "Encoding is #{Encoding.default_external}"

template 'C:/file.udl' do
  rights :full_control, 'Everyone'
  action :create
  source 'file.udl.erb'
end
```

And the template (UTF-8 encoded at the source but not after being transferred to the target node):

```
[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=MyPassword;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUsername;Initial Catalog=MyCat;Data Source=MyServer
```

The resultant ANSI file can't be read by OLE ... is there anyway to convince Chef/ruby to write the file in UTF-8?

Comment: So the place to start debugging is to figure out where in the whole Chef system the encoding is being corrupted. Use `knife cookbook show` to check what things look like on the Chef Server?

Comment: Also this should probably be removed on SO and filed as an Issue on our GitHub repo.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger ... I've filed an issue on github for chef team, but was hoping someone had a clever workaround or something I'm just missing.

Comment: In general there aren't quick workarounds for encoding issues :) Though in general we tend to be encoding-neutral and just treat data as byte streams for file storage.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach, hacking Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateContext

in `libraries/template_hacking.rb`

```rb
require 'chef/mixin/template'

# Hacking Chef loads template with specific encoding
# Usage in your recipe:
#
#   template 'my_utf8_file' do
#     source 'my_utf8_file'
#     variables(
#       __encoding__: 'utf-8',
#       name: '你好'
#     )
#   end
#
unless Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateContext.public_methods.include?(:_origin_render_template)
  class Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateContext
    alias_method :_origin_render_template, :_render_template
    def _render_template(template, context)
      encoding = context[:__encoding__] && context[:__encoding__].upcase
      if template && encoding && template.encoding.name != encoding
        Chef::Log.info("Encoding template to #{encoding}")
        template.force_encoding encoding
      end
      _origin_render_template(template, context)
    end
  end
end
```

in recipe `recipes/my_recipe.rb`

```rb
template 'my_utf8_file' do
  source 'my_utf8_file'
  variables(
    __encoding__: 'utf-8',
    name: '你好'
  )
end
```